# Circuits - A AND NOT A

Tags: logic

Okay, so I am supposed to make a **truth table** from this circuit: [image: Circuit]
But A AND NOT A doesn't make any sense... Same 4 the B AND NOT B... And suggestions ?

Comment: A and not A is always FALSE.

Comment: Well, you have an odd expression : FALSE comes out of both the "and" gates, hence $F$ is the constant value $0$. So in your truth table, the value of $F$ will always be zero.

Comment: There are four possible pairs of inputs for $(A,B)$, so put these as rows in your truth table and find the outputs from each gate. `A AND NOT A` does make sense: as @Mauro and Anton have said, it is `FALSE` for both possible values of $A$

Comment: So the table will look something like this: https://gyazo.com/52d62d73e5c6c17633f82f4353508b23

Comment: Yes, That is what I would expect.  A little dull

Comment: You now know the correct truth table for this circuit. As it turns out, however, people do build such "boring" circuits sometimes in real life. The reason is that while the truth table says what the _stable_ output of the circuit is, in actual devices the input may change from time to time and there may be _transitional_ effects depending on how long it takes each component to reach its new stable state. For example, see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/how-to-turn-continuous-signal-into-a-short-pulse-using-logic-gates